# 2 if else statements and 2 different $types

Tags: php

Basically I am working a site store and having problems with it. Nothing online seems to have what I need to figure out. I am having the first if else statement working fine and the second not working properly. Here is the coding tell me what is wrong or what I can do different.

```
<?php
$adsql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store_items WHERE userid='$id2'");
while($adrow = mysql_fetch_array($adsql)){
    $type = $adrow['type'];(this is int)
                               $item = $adrow['id'];
    if ($type == 1) {
        $item1 = "<center>You have bought this already</center>";
    } else {
        $item1 = This is where item1 is bought

            }
    if ($type == 2) {
        $item2 = "<center>You have bought this already</center>";
    } else {
        $item2 = This is where item2 is bought
            </table>
            ";
              }
      }
    ?>
```

Its retrieving the last number not all the numbers which in return only showing 1 of if else statements instead of both. Any idea what is wrong be a appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! How are you sanitizing the `$id2` variable? I believe this script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities because you have not shown any sanitizing for `$id2` variable. Please use [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent these vulnerabilities. Thanks.

Comment: [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be complete, concise, representative and *correct* (free from syntax errors). Also, pick and use an [indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) to make your code readable. A good code editor/IDE can auto-indent code, which will make certain types of mistakes obvious.

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements.

Comment: `<center>` isn't [semantic](http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/5-site-structure/2-semantic-markup.html), and I suspect the [`<table>`](http://davespicks.com/writing/essays/notables.html) is being used for layout rather than as an actual table, which is inappropriate. HTML is for document structure. Use CSS for presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines:

```
$item1 = This is where item1 is bought
```

and

```
$item2 = This is where item2 is bought
```

Should be:

```
$item1 = "This is where item1 is bought";
```

and

```
$item2 = "This is where item2 is bought";
```

Without the quotes, the statements are syntactically incorrect.

Comment: I suspect the OP has eliminated code and replaced it with placeholder text that happens to not be standard. If that were in the actual script, it would generate a parse error and not run at all.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, I think you're right.

Comment: IT is and the $id2 is a session

Comment: @user1079456, please post the code as it is.

Comment: I finally figured out what I had to do. I made 2 separate MySQL query's. Example $adsql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store_itmes WHERE userid='$id2' AND type=1") and that type is switched to 2 for the other one.